# JAVA swing application+executing jar

Tags: java, jar

I'm a newbie to java programming. I downloaded netbeans (java EE) bundle in ubuntu and wrote a simple swing application which runs fine from with netbeans. I tried running it from the terminal by typing "java -jar " as netbeans suggested and i got "could not find main class" error. So i tried to check the classpath by using echo $CLASSPATH and got nothing. Then i set the classpath using $ set CLASSPATH=. When i again tried "java -jar , i got the same error (main class not found). echo $CLASSPATH again gives nothing even though i tried setting classpath. Please help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Provide an entry point to the graphical interface. I typically call this class **Main**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

           java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       new MyJFrame();
                   }
               });  
          }
}
```

Next, click the **Files** tab (next to projects tab on the top left) and look for a file called Mainfest.mf.  You will need to add a **Main-Class:** attribute to this file.

> Main-Class: Main

This tells the jar what to execute when double-clicked or run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Netbeans, but I do know what `java` wants on the command line when using the `-jar` option.

One possibility is the jar's manifest is missing a `Main-class` declaration.  This declaration tells where the entry point for the program should be when using the `-jar` invocation option.  It specifies a particular class having a `main` method.

To verify what I'm saying is the case, try the following on the jar produced by Netbeans (*I'm assuming `bash` shell because of `$` prompt in your question .. tell me if I'm wrong*):

```
$ jar xf my.jar META-INF
$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Main-Class
```

If that comes up empty, or doesn't name your class, then your next SO question might be "How do I tell Netbeans what class is the entry point when making a jar".